# Angular Material Timepicker Localization

Tags: angular, angular-material, datetimepicker

I need to setup a macedonian localization for my angular datetimepicker

I'm currently facing an issue with setting Macedonian localization for the NgxMaterialTimepickerModule in my Angular project.

I've tried setting the locale using the following approach in my module:

```
import { NgxMaterialTimepickerModule } from 'ngx-material-timepicker';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    NgxMaterialTimepickerModule.setLocale('mk')
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

However, despite trying this method, I haven't been successful in getting the timepicker to display in Macedonian. I've also attempted installing the Macedonian locale using npm (npm install --save @angular/common@locale/mk), but I encountered permission issues when trying to fetch the locale data from GitHub.

How to properly set Macedonian localization for `NgxMaterialTimepickerModule`? Any alternative approaches or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.